# Removing directories not accessed in X days

Tags: files, filesystems, find, zsh, cache

I have written some scripts for downloading and caching music, and I like to delete the directories in the cache location that have not been accessed in X days. I can do that via:

```
 gfind "$music_dir" -mindepth 1 -type d -atime +90 -print -delete
```

But this immediately sets the access times of all the remaining dirs to now, which is very undesirable. What can I do?

PS: I'm using macOS, but I'd prefer a cross-platform (Unixy) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chflags` (or `chattr` depending on your OS) to set the directories to immutable:

```bsh
sudo chflags -R uimmutable "$music_dir"
gfind "$music_dir" -mindepth 1 -type d -atime +90 -print > 'delete_list.txt'
sudo chflags -R nouimmutable "$music_dir"
cat 'delete_list.txt' | xargs rm -rf
```